# non-kosher publishers

Tags: jewish-books

Are there any discussions in the Posekim about learning or owning kosher, non-manuscript books/Sefarim that were printed by "non-Kosher" people?

I know Harav Yaakov Hillel forbade them while Harav Mazuz permitted them as long as you remove the first pages (which had the name of the "non-Kosher" person asked about in particular case he was asked about) (also my old Rosh Yeshiva I heard permitted); I am looking for what others have said.

Comment: Like mikraos gedolos?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was thinking like the Berg Zohars.

Comment: What about using tzuras hadaf in a bavli gemara?

Comment: ...what does this say about using StackExchange?

Comment: R' Mazuz said it was fine to use the work as long as you are careful to avoid hakarat hatov to the person who produced it and amirat davar besheim omero?

Comment: You're asking if the guy who owns the printing house and makes the profit off the sales has to be a Yere Shamayim?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I guess it has something to do with his name being evil...

Comment: @SethJ Harav Yaakov Hilel seems to Oser it pretty strongly.

Comment: Aser what? I'm trying to get clarity, not start a debate.

Comment: Did I understand the question correctly, then?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with who is making the money.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/53/index.htm#_ftnref_3953) (quoting the Taz) says that a Chazzan should pray from the communities siddur, since it was written for Hashem's sake.

However, he says, that if the siddur is printed there is no difference between siddurim.

One can learn this two ways:

1. Since the main Kedusha falls only though handwriting (for example, a chumash [or Tikkun] doesn't have the same rules as a Sefer Torah), there is no real difference between "holy" publishers and "un-holy" publishers.
2. Since there were only a few printers, one can assume that they were all printed with the same intent. Therefore, if one is bad so are the rest. If so, even if the siddurim don't have the proper holiness, there is nothing one can do about it.

---

This case could be a practical difference.

If the first way is the correct way, then (possibly) one may learn from works published by kofrim. If the second way is correct, then one should still look for books written by holy Jews.

---

However, the Tzitz Eliezer quotes a Chazon Ish who says that modern printing works differently than the printing of a few centuries ago.

Back then, every print was done with direct human power. Therefore, there is still some (inherent) Kedusha in printed works. Nowadays, when one just presses a button and the printing is done automatically, unless the works are made for learning, one may destroy them by hand.

Therefore, it's possible that even according to the second interpretation, one may be able to learn from those books.